# VB Noob: use Mod to add an extra class at the end of the row

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

So this is a total noob question, but I'm trying to use VB in an aspx file to add a class at the end of a row, and it's not going well. What am I doing wrong?

```
<div class="compare-item-wrapper<%If (n1) Mod 4 = 0 Then " last","" %>">
```

I'm getting a syntax error. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I would use a `Panel`(which is rendered as `div`) and use the codebehind for your logic. ASP.NET is not classic ASP (or PHP).

Comment: "it's not going well" What does that mean? Does it explode?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve and do you need Modulo for that ? This would add a class each 4 div, is that what you want to do ? Maybe it would be better to use css selectectors to achieve what you want to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would either use the `If` function to make an expression:

```
<div class="compare-item-wrapper<%= If(n1 Mod 4 = 0, " last", "") %>">
```

or use `End If` and a literal value inside the `If` statement:

```
<div class="compare-item-wrapper<% If n1 Mod 4 = 0 Then %> last<% End If %>">
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I ended up using because 0 was giving me the first: <div class="compare-item-wrapper<%If n1 Mod 4 = 3 Then %> last<%End If %>">